# Clear a subform in Access using a button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

On my form I have the Done button that when clicked will clear the form and should clear the subform then close the form. I can get everything to work expect I can't get my subform to clear no matter what I have tried. 
I have tried doing

```
Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.Filter = Null
Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.FilterOn = False
Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.Requery
```

and
    Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form = ""
and 
    Me.subformGroupVolunteers= ""

Please help!! Thanks!!

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_GroupVolunteers(GroupName, Leader, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, EmergencyContactName, EmergencyContactNumber, RegistrationNumber)" & _
 "VALUES('" & Me.txtGroupName & "','" & Me.cboLeader & "','" & Me.txtFirstName & "','" & Me.txtLastName & "','" & Me.txtPhone & _
 "','" & Me.txtEmail & "','" & Me.txtEmergencyContactName & "','" & Me.txtEmergencyContactNumber & "','" & Me.txtRegistrationNumber & "');"

'clear form
cmdClear_Click
'refresh subform
Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.Requery
Me.cboLeader.SetFocus

 End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
Me.cboLeader = ""
Me.txtFirstName = ""
Me.txtLastName = ""
Me.txtPhone = ""
Me.txtEmail = ""
Me.txtEmergencyContactName = ""
Me.txtEmergencyContactNumber = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
Dim RegistrationMsg As Integer
RegistrationMsg = MsgBox("Your registration number is:" & Me.txtRegistrationNumber & ". Please keep this for your records. You will need this if you want to delete or update your registration!", vbOKOnly, "Registration Number")

cmdClear_Click
Me.txtRegistrationNumber = ""
Me.txtGroupName = ""

Dim varControl As Variant
For Each varControl In Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.Controls
If varControl.ControlType = acTextBox Or varControl.ControlType = acLabel Then
    If varControl.Tag = 1 Then
        varControl = ""
        End If
        End If
    Next varControl

DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Is the form / subform bound (i.e. has a RecordSource)? Why do you need to do anything before closing the form?

Comment: @Andre451 By clear I mean clearing all the data that had been inserted into the subform based on the form.

Comment: Sorry, that is still totally unclear (no pun intended).

Comment: @Andre451 at this point puns are appreciated. I know it would be much easier to show then explain so I will do my best again. I have a subform that is tied to the main form. When I end information on that form it is populated on the subform and inserted into a table. Once I click submit I need the subform to clear out it's contents.

Comment: By "tied" I assume that both the form and the subform have a **RecordSource**, i.e. they show the data of a table or query. The usual way to "clear" both forms and prepare for new data entry is: go to a **new record** in the main form. Since no subform records are linked to it, it clears automatically. --- If this doesn't help, please upload a screenshot of form+subform to https://imgur.com/ and post the link here.

Comment: @Andre451 https://imgur.com/sbAYZRl

Comment: Thanks. What is the code behind the Add/Clear/Done buttons? Please edit your question and add it there. And I still don't understand why you need to clear the subform before closing the form - isn't this the data you want to save? Or is this a temporary table, and the data gets copied to the actual table?

Comment: @Andre451 this is a temporary table the information gets copied to the actual table. Think of it this way the subform is just for review purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the subform is bound to (= shows the data of) `tbl_GroupVolunteers`, which is a **temporary** table.

You didn't show the code to copy the data to the **actual** table. But after you have done that, simply do a

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tbl_GroupVolunteers"
Me.subformGroupVolunteers.Form.Requery
```

and that's it.